# Update button text based on recyclerview item count

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am creating a android project. I have a recyclerview and a button below it. I want to change my button text based on how many items are on the recyclerview.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide what you have come up with so far? Please post any code that you have come it so far, plus make sure to read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Before you set the Adapter of your recyclerView, get the size of your Arraylist, then pass it has a text inyour button after parsing it to a string. It should work for you